# Quadratic map has non-trivial zero?

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

Let $Q(x):\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ - Surjective function.

$$Q(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1(x_1,x_2) \\
q_2(x_2,x_3) \\
q_3(x_3,x_4) \\
q_4(x_4,x_1)
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $q_i(x)$ is a quadratic form.

Does it exist $x \neq 0$ such that $Q(x)=0 $ ?

I tried to solve it by system of linear equations, using surjective property..without results... So, maybe have any ideas, answers?

Comment: If it is surjective, then every element in $\Bbb R^4$ has a pre-image, in particular...

Comment: yes, it's definetly right, but how does  it helps?